# How to disable a virtualbox nic when not in use to stop it sucking power?

Tags: virtualbox, power

I'm using powertop to see what's eating battery.

A massive chunk is apparently going on nic:vboxnet0 which I do need when I fire up my VMs, but when they're not in action, I don't need to be spending 2.5W on this!

Unless powertop is reporting it incorrectly.

Comment: I doubt a virtual NIC is using any measurable power at all, especially if not in use. If in Windows you should be able to go to Network Adapter and right click and disable, but you didn't state your host OS.

Comment: running powertop within a VM would be rather suspect. VM software provides an abstract hardware layer between the physical hardware and the guest OS, so what the guest OS sees as actual hardware, isn't. do all your power monitoring from the host. any power the host hardware draws on behalf of the guest OS should be reflected there, but instead on the real nic.

Comment: Hi @acejavelin, sorry, I'm on Ubuntu (18.04) - I thought the reference to powertop would identify the Os, but perhps it's available for windows too.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm not running powertop in a VM. I only mentioned VMs because that's something I use the host laptop for that requires the virtual adaptor. I agree that a virtual nic should not be using much/any measurable power, I did think it suspect, but wanted to check.